# Which chat message was I banned from chat for?

Tags: discussion, chat

I've been banned from chat for 7 days.

The only information I've been given is the [following](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16936706#16936706)

> @menotalk @andrewgrimm clearly you guys don't like each other, but
>   poking each other with sticks is not going to be tolerated. I suggest
>   that you both make sure the other is on your ignore list and simply
>   avoid talking. You'll both probably be much happier.

Which chat message was I banned for?

Was it for purely for a chat message that was something like

> The sooner MeNoTalk [note: no at symbol] is banned, the better

or were previous chat messages involved as well?

Comment: I do not mind my name to be there, it is ok if you want to write it.

Comment: @doc, LOL :) :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's ok for him to clarify - it's not like he can do it in chat.

Comment: @Doc at least they're being consistent… :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd be happy to provide some further explanation, though do to privacy concerns there are limitations to how much I can say.  Let me start by indicating that I was not actually the one who directly issued the suspension, but I do understand the full reason of why it was given and agree with the reasoning.

Looking at the chat history, it is clear that there has been an ongoing issue between you and the other involved user for an extended time period.  It is also clear that numerous chat users have found this conflict to be a drain on the community in the chat room and are sick of it.

In this case in particular, all I can say from public information is that one or more community members flagged posts from the latest round of the fight (which started almost immediately upon another member returning to chat).  The responses from both parties were very similar in terms of being rude to the other, so both sides were penalized for further continuing the conflict in a way that doesn't meet the standards for chat.

I decided to post my comment in the hopes of avoiding further continuation of the conflict that has clearly become a destructive disruption to the community based on the overwhelming response of stars that my plea to simply avoid each other garnered.

If you are still unsure about why you were suspended, I would be happy to chat with you some more about it privately after you come off chat suspension.

Comment: do you mind chatting with me if you around about why was I banned for one month while he was banned for 7 days? not that I mind the ban, I just want to know what kind of reasons made whoever banned me to do this?

Comment: @MeNoTalk - sure, I responded in a private chat message.  Let me know if you weren't able to get to it.

Comment: thanks for the response mate I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Really...

There are people who I really do not like and there are people out there who do not like me. It is a fact of life. And guess what: There are people who for whatever inconceivable reason *do* like that person I do not like. Yes, even love them. And these people who do not like me: Some cannot tell to their friends what exactly the problem with me is but they do not like me. Bad luck.

But now I have a solid reason for my dislike: XYZ is X-ist ! Whatever it is, it is really, really bad. Every human who is not X-ist must recognize that.

Now how do I handle the situation ?
I can say that I find his/her behavior not ok. In public or in private. XYZ knows now what I think and he/she can think over it.
Perhaps he/she is sorry. Everyone could make mistakes. I can accept that or not.
Perhaps he/she is aggressive. Then I could block him/her.
Whatever he/she thinks or does, the community have only a marginal influence on what XYZ really thinks. But what the community could do is not tolerating behavior which violates the rules of the community. And that is ok. If XYZ continues intolerable behavior, he will be punished.

The important thing about the community rules are that they should be fair. They should not be invoked because you have the wrong race, religion, sex or whatever, they are invoked because rules have been broken.

But I can also think that what the person did is inexcusable, and therefore I try to use the community for my own personal vendetta. That means I do not use chat for talking or conversing or solving conflicts, but to stir up the confrontation in the hope to get backup for punishing XYZ *without* community rules.

And that is not what the intention of the chat is. It is NOT intended to raise conflict. It is NOT intended to draw in the community in a personal conflict. Guess what ? People can read. They know the conflict and are NOT interested.
REALLY ABSOLUTELY NOT INTERESTED !
Stirring up confrontation is violating the rules, too.

Is that understandable ?

Comment: This answer is not informative. Also, what vendetta?

Answer (score -4):

I was banned for 30 days for the same reason you were banned for 7 days, I do not mind the ban at all, it was worth it, at least I won't be around for sometime until I cool down (that's what SE says!), plus you are already in my ignore list (again) so no more conflicts in the future, Regarding your ban, 2 days left for the ban to be removed! I am sure you will miss me and my short fuse! no more excitement for you dude ;)